# from where i Copy "webtemp.xml" and "onet.xml" files of standared sharepoint 2013 team site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-definition

I want to create site definition in VS 2012. But for webtemp.xml and Onet.xml files,I want to copy content from webtemp.xml and Onet.xml files of standared sharepoint 2013 "team site" for my site definition. where these files "webtemp.xml" and "Onet.xml" are located for sharepoint team site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, but when you want to look at the standard `onet.xml`or `webtemp.xml` files you just have to check the 15-hive.

The `onet.xml` for the Standard Team site is located under:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPlATE\SiteTemplates\sts\xml
```

Two important notes about this: Under `SiteTemplates` you actually find all of the Standard Site templates. `sts` in this case represents the team site. You might also want to check out the `features` folder to see all of the supplied features.

Based on the STS-template you can create your own template and take ideas from the standard.

---

To see all available site templates and their names try the following in PowerShell:

```
get-spweb http://<yoursharepoint> | %{$_.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033)} | select title, name
```

I get the following output:

```
Title                                                       Name
-----                                                       ----
Global template                                             GLOBAL#0
Team Site                                                   STS#0
Blank Site                                                  STS#1
Document Workspace                                          STS#2
Basic Meeting Workspace                                     MPS#0
Blank Meeting Workspace                                     MPS#1
Decision Meeting Workspace                                  MPS#2
Social Meeting Workspace                                    MPS#3
Multipage Meeting Workspace                                 MPS#4
Central Admin Site                                          CENTRALADMIN#0
Wiki Site                                                   WIKI#0
Blog                                                        BLOG#0
Group Work Site                                             SGS#0
Tenant Admin Site                                           TENANTADMIN#0
App Template                                                APP#0
App Catalog Site                                            APPCATALOG#0
Access Services Site                                        ACCSRV#0
Access Services Site Internal                               ACCSVC#0
Access Services Site                                        ACCSVC#1
Document Center                                             BDR#0
Developer Site                                              DEV#0
Academic Library                                            DOCMARKETPLACESITE#0
eDiscovery Center                                           EDISC#0
eDiscovery Case                                             EDISC#1
(obsolete) Records Center                                   OFFILE#0
Records Center                                              OFFILE#1
Shared Services Administration Site                         OSRV#0
PerformancePoint                                            PPSMASite#0
Business Intelligence Center                                BICenterSite#0
SharePoint Portal Server Site                               SPS#0
SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space                     SPSPERS#0
Storage And Social SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space  SPSPERS#2
Storage Only SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space        SPSPERS#3
Social Only SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space         SPSPERS#4
Empty SharePoint Portal Server Personal Space               SPSPERS#5
Personalization Site                                        SPSMSITE#0
Contents area Template                                      SPSTOC#0
Topic area template                                         SPSTOPIC#0
News Site                                                   SPSNEWS#0
Publishing Site                                             CMSPUBLISHING#0
Publishing Site                                             BLANKINTERNET#0
Press Releases Site                                         BLANKINTERNET#1
Publishing Site with Workflow                               BLANKINTERNET#2
News Site                                                   SPSNHOME#0
Site Directory                                              SPSSITES#0
Community area template                                     SPSCOMMU#0
Report Center                                               SPSREPORTCENTER#0
Collaboration Portal                                        SPSPORTAL#0
Enterprise Search Center                                    SRCHCEN#0
Profiles                                                    PROFILES#0
Publishing Portal                                           BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER#0
My Site Host                                                SPSMSITEHOST#0
Enterprise Wiki                                             ENTERWIKI#0
Project Site                                                PROJECTSITE#0
Product Catalog                                             PRODUCTCATALOG#0
Community Site                                              COMMUNITY#0
Community Portal                                            COMMUNITYPORTAL#0
Basic Search Center                                         SRCHCENTERLITE#0
Basic Search Center                                         SRCHCENTERLITE#1
Visio Process Repository                                    visprus#0
```

As you can see, "Document Center" is BDR#0, hence the path is: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\BDR`

Comment: Thanks! Similarly, what is the path for standard SP2013 "document center" ?

Comment: I updated the answer for you.

Comment: I have two more question. 1. I just copied the contents from Onet.xml file of sts and replaced it with my custom site definition Onet.xml file. will it work ? or I need to change something in the copied code ? 2.Should I need to change something in Webtemp.xml file of my custom site definition ?